# How to get resolve ElasticSearch warning message "Transport Handler Not Found" on spring boot application console?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

We have two Spring boot applications using the same Elasticsearch database. The queries work fine. But the console of the second spring boot application is always flooded with these warning messages as soon as it boots up. Is there any configuration we are missing, either in the Spring boot app or at Elasticsearch?

```
2021-02-16 16:15:03.757  INFO 19828 --- [main] o.s.d.e.c.TransportClientFactoryBean: Adding transport node : 127.0.0.1:9300
2021-02-16 16:15:04.760  WARN 19828 --- [ient_boss][T#1]] o.e.transport.TransportService: Transport response handler not found of id [1]
2021-02-16 16:15:04.932  WARN 19828 --- [ient_boss][T#2]] o.e.transport.TransportService: Transport response handler not found of id [3]
2021-02-16 16:15:08.104  WARN 19828 --- [ient_boss][T#7]] o.e.transport.TransportService: Transport response handler not found of id [9]
2021-02-16 16:15:13.232  WARN 19828 --- [ient_boss][T#8]] o.e.transport.TransportService: Transport response handler not found of id [59]
```